# Showing $x_t = \delta_t + \sum_{j=1}^tw_j$

Tags: time-series

Suppose we have the random walk with drift model

$$x_t = \delta+x_{t-1}+w_t$$
for $t = 1, 2, ...$ with initial condition $x_0=0$ and where $w_t$ is white noise. The constant $\delta$ is called the drift, when $\delta$=0, the equation above is simply a random walk. $t$ is the time. We may rewrite this as the cumulative sum of white noise variates:

$$x_t = \delta t+\sum_{j=1}^tw_j$$

What I have tried to show this:

$$\delta t+\sum_{j=1}^tw_j=\delta+x_{t-1}+w_t \\ 
x_{t-1}=\delta(t-1)+\sum_{j=1}^tw_j-w_t$$

If I remember summation tricks properly, then

$$\sum_{j=1}^t w_j-w_t = \sum_{j=1}^{t+1}w_j$$

So we have

$$x_{t-1} = \delta(t-1)+\sum_{j=1}^{t+1}w_j$$

Comment: What are your hypothesis and what are your aim here ?

Comment: @EDX My objective was to show the cumulative sum follows from the first equation. By the looks of it, I am fairly uncertain with the summation switch, as I have doubts it might be $t-1$ on the top instead. So clarification on this is really helpful!

Comment: What is $\delta$ ? Please if you can set all the name and characteristics of your parameters I could help you better

Comment: @EDX I have updated it in the post

Comment: If $\delta$ is a constant independant on $t$ we can write $x_t-x_{t-1}=\delta + w_t$ then telescoping the left $x_n -x_0 =(n+1)\delta + \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} w_i$